# Video recording asus transformer

Tags: video-recording

I would like to record video of the screen of my asus transformer. I don't need high fps. 12 to 15 fps would be more than enough for my needs. I tried searching for an app on the market for this purpose. But there doesn't seem to be any app that allows me to record video of the screen of my asus transformer.

So, I was wondering if there was any app that i am not aware off or maybe some other way through which i can record some video of my asus screen.

Someone at #android proposed the idea of using the hdmi out on my asus to connect it to an hdmi input on a pc. But unfortunately i only have an hdmi out on my pc as well... If hdmi is the only option I have, could anyone please tell me if there is any way of making my laptop receive hdmi signals?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same problem and I think I've got the solution. I'm thinking of 2 ways:

1. Buy an HDMI to component or HDPVR converter and buy a capture card (cheapest)
2. Buy an HDMI capture cart (very expensive).

You have to make sure the HDMI capture card will be HDCP compatible because otherwise it will refuse to receive the encrypted video.  Of course, that's the same for the converter but that costs about 40 euro.